# Canvas drop down text animation

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

The following code animates the given text from top to bottom
(fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ht5oaep/)

I want it to run infinitely (when the text disappears at the bottom - to reappear at the top)

How to approach this?

Is there an easier way than the constant drawing and clearing of the text?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// fills canvas with given text
function draw(txt, y) {
    var txtHeight = 10;
    var w = Math.ceil(ctx.measureText(txt).width);
    var txt = new Array(w * 2).join(' ' + txt + ' ');

    var total_text_height = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(canvas.height / txtHeight); i++) {
        total_text_height += txtHeight;
        ctx.fillText(txt, 0, i * txtHeight + y);
    }
}

// animate
var y = 0;
function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    draw('STACK-OVERFLOW', y);
    y += 1;
}
setInterval(animate, 50);
```

Comment: Ive tried checking if the total_text_height > canvas.height
and then rerendering the text
but the browser freezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use %(Modulo) to re-position texts.

this operator calculates the remainder divded with following number.
(sorry for bad english)

10%3 //1
4%2//0
56%6 // 2

So eventually I mean Y%(ScreenWidth) give you the answer.

Comment: mod worked!!
Actually ctx.fillText(txt, 0, i * txtHeight + y % txtHeight)  gave me the answer i wanted.
How y % txtHeight is filling the empty part on the top?